# Probability of selecting a specific combination of three variables

Tags: combinatorics

**Question stem**

"Barry is on a weekend fishing trip with his friends. He always goes fishing at Landon Bay, which is home to three types of fish: Snapper, Barramundi and Tuna. There is a very large number of fish in the Bay and, on this particular day, there are twice as many Snapper as Barramundi, and twice as many Barramundi as Tuna.

Barry catches four fish. The probability, correct to one decimal place, that two of the fish are Snapper (S), one is Barramundi (B) and the other is Tuna (T) is?" (From the 2016 Derrick Ha Mathematical Methods Examination 2 Trial Exam B)

**The answer I was given**

Pr$(Two\: Snappers)={4 \choose 2}\times{2 \choose 1}\times (\frac{4}{7})^2\times(\frac{2}{7})\times(\frac{1}{7})=\frac{384}{2401}$

If I understand correctly, $(\frac{4}{7})^2\times(\frac{2}{7})\times(\frac{1}{7})$ refers to the probability of one combination of 2S, 1B and 1T.

**What I don't get**

Is how they derived ${4 \choose 2}\times{2 \choose 1}$, which I assume returns the number of ways that this combination can be achieved.

**What I have tried:**

- Drawing a tree diagram, which is what I usually do for these sorts of
  questions. But it's too unwieldy for this question.
- Using the hyper-geometric distribution formula - which probably
  doesn't work because there is effectively no replacement for this
  question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be $\binom{\color{red}{4}}{2}\binom{2}{1}\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^2 \left(\frac{2}{7}\right)\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)$. You are correct that the product of fractions counts the probability of a specific arrangement of $S,S,B,T$. The product of binomial coefficients counts the number of ways to arrange these four fish. $\binom{4}{2}$ is the number of choices we have for where to position the $S$'s, while $\binom{2}{1}$ is the number of choices we then have to position the $B$. The $T$ must then go in the last place.

We can write out all the possibilities to check that this is correct. First, just listing out the $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways to position the $S$'s, we have:
\begin{align*}
S,S,\_,\_\\
S, \_,S,\_\\
S, \_, \_, S\\
\_, S, S, \_\\
\_, S, \_, S\\
\_, \_, S, S
\end{align*}
Now for the remaining two blanks we can fill them in in the order $B,T$ or $T, B$. So the total number of arrangements is $\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1}=12$:
\begin{align*}
S,S,B,T\\
S,S, T, B\\
S, B,S,T\\
S, T, S, B\\
S, B, T, S\\
S, T, B, S\\
B, S, S, T\\
T, S, S, B\\
B, S, T, S\\
T, S, B, S\\
B, T, S, S\\
T, B, S, S
\end{align*}