# General formula for determining the probability of combinations of three objects from a large population

Tags: combinatorics

I've been toying around with a generalized solution to questions such as:

[Probability of selecting a specific combination of three variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3370179/probability-of-selecting-a-specific-combination-of-three-variables)

So far this is what I have...

**Is the following formula true?**

A large population exists with object types $A$, $B$ and $C$ such that the probability of selecting object $A$ is $p_A$, $B$ is $p_B$, $C$ is $p_C$ and $p_A+p_B+p_C=1$.

To ascertain the probability of selecting $n$ objects from this population with
 $n_A$ of $A$, $n_B$ of $B$, $n_C$ of $C$ and $n=n_A+n_B+n_C$:

\begin{multline}
\text{Pr}(n_A\: \text{of}\: A,\: n_B\: \text{of}\: B,\: n_C\: \text{of}\: C)=\\
{n \choose n_A}\cdot{n-n_A \choose n_B}\cdot{n-n_A-n_B \choose n_C}\cdot {(p_A)}^{n_A}\cdot{(p_B)}^{n_B}\cdot{(p_C)}^{n_C}
\end{multline}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have discovered the [Multinomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution)! Notice that the binomial coefficients can be simplified to:
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{n_A}\binom{n-n_A}{n_B} \binom{n-n_A-n_B}{n_C} &=\frac{n!}{n_A!(n-n_A)!} \frac{(n-n_A)!}{n_B!(n-n_A-n_B)!}\frac{(n-n_A-n_B)!}{n_C!(n-n_A-n_B-n_C)!}\\
&=\frac{n!}{n_A!n_B!n_C!}.
\end{align*}
The $(n-n_A-n_b-n_C)!$ term disappears because this is equal to $0!=1$.

Also not that you need to assume each sample from the population is independent in order for your formula to hold.